# With Linux shell commands, how can I edit a list of files fed through a pipestream into a CSV format?

Tags: linux, shell, file, csv, path

With Linux shell commands, how can I recursively search a directory and output the list of files into a CSV file of two values; path & file?

So for example, let’s say I have the following file structure…

```
home/readme.txt.
home/web/fruit/grapes.pdf
home/web/animals/mammals/bears.gif
```

I want a CSV file with the output…

```
home,readme.txt
home/web/fruit,grapes.pdf
home/web/animals/mammals,bears.gif
```

So far, the closest I’ve come to this is using the command:

```
 find home -type f | sed ‘s/\//,/g’
```

But it’s not quite right, as the above command ends up replacing all the forward slashes with commas, not just the last one.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can do this?

For reference, I’m using a Redhat Enterprise Linux Server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the longest prefix ending with a `/` which you can find with `.*\/`.  You then want to use that prefix, which you can capture with `\(.*\)\/` and replay with `\1`.

So, update your sed to `sed 's/\(.*\)\//\1,/'`

Giving:

```
find home -type f | sed 's/\(.*\)\//\1,/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`. As regular expressions are greedy with this tool, it will replace the last occurence of the character `/` by `,`:

```
sed 's#\(.*\)/\(.*\)#\1,\2#' file
```

If you need to do this for all files in a directory, use this:

```
find -type f -exec sed 's#\(.*\)/\(.*\)#\1,\2#' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

When I attempted this, I received the error message "find: missing arguement to '-exec'"

I suspect I made a typo, but I managed to get borrible's code to work, so I haven't gone back and tested that theory,

Thanks again!